# Can I override the html_name for a tabularinline field in the admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

**Is it possible to override the html naming of fields in TabularInline admin forms so they won't contain dashes?**

I'm trying to apply the knowledge obtained [here](http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/autocomplete-form-widget-foreignkey-model-fields/) to create a TabularInline admin form that has the auto-complete feature.

It all works except that Django insists in naming the fields in a tabularinline queryset as something in the lines of:

```
[model]_set-[index]-[field]
```

So, if my model is TravelLogClient and my foreign key field is company, the fields in the HTML form for the three entries in the tabularinline queryset will be:

```
travellogclient_set-0-company
travellogclient_set-1-company
travellogclient_set-2-company
```

The problem is that javascript dislikes identifiers with dashes in them. So the javascript fails and the autocomplete doesn't work.

THIS IS ONLY A PROBLEM WITH TABULAR INLINE forms! If I use [Jannis' autocomplete example](http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/autocomplete-form-widget-foreignkey-model-fields/) on a non tabular admin form field, it works just fine because the field name doesn't have the "`..._set-[index]-...`" portion in the HTML and javascript.

Rather than submitting a patch to django's source code changing dashes for underscores on `contrib.forms.forms.py` and `contrib.forms.formsets.py`, it occurred to me that it is possible that behavior can be overridden somehow.

Failing that, what is the easiest way to make those dashes in the html_name become underscores instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to access these fields with javascript?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking: Property names containing dashes are completely fine in JS, it's just that you have to access the properties with object['the-prop'] instead of the erroneous  object.the-prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paolo and Guðmundur are right. I modified my usage in the javascript according to Guðmundur's suggestion and things now work as expected - no django intervention needed.

Sorry for the mental lapse...

Thanks!